# Python PyCharm can't find executables in /usr/local/bin

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pycharm

I have a problem that started by trying to execute

```py
some_aws_command = 'aws s3 <do some stuff>' # the real command has been purposefully obfuscated but that doesn't matter here
subprocess.Popen(some_aws_command.split()).wait()
```

Which resulted in a weird error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aws'
```

After some digging, I found that through the execution environment (I'm using PyCharm's run functionality) there's no longer access to the `aws` cli executable.

The following code behaves differently from the terminal than from PyCharm's Run:

```py
import shutil
shutil.which('aws')
```

Via the terminal it returns the expected path - `'/usr/local/bin/aws'`, but via PyCharm's Run, it just returns `None`. This was working previously, and I can't figure out what change caused the break.

Any ideas on how to get it to work again?

Comment: Maybe you should add more details. Are you trying to create a Run Configuration? Are you trying to run these commands in PyCharms terminal? Are you trying to run those commands in a script? PyCharm is a big IDE with a million different features. Please help us understand what you are actually trying to do, so that we have some kind of context.

Comment: why not use `/usr/local/bin/aws s3 <do some stuff>`

Comment: you should check `echo $PATH` to see if you have `/usr/local/bin` in `PATH`. Maybe PyCharm has some option to set custom `PATH` or use `PATH` from system - and this can make problem.

Comment: You need to activate the venv that has aws installed.